# How to apply a statistical test on either a bi-modal distribution OR how to transform it to parametric?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, python, data-transformation, bimodal

I have lifetimevalue (LTV) data for 3 groups in my set. For each group, their respective LTV looks bi-modal. 
I need to test if there is a statistical significance between those groups with respect to the LTV. 
Here is an example PDF of LTV for one of the group:

[image]

My questions:
1.) Is there a way to transform this to a normal distribution so that I can apply Anova or Tukey HSD Test?
2.) Is there a test I can apply on bi-modal data to test either the mean or median (if 1. does not work)?

I have tried a log-transform by adding a constant (i.e 1000) to the data since I have Null values. However, even this transformation did not result in a normal-like PDF. It stayed pretty much bi-modal.

I addition to the approach, I wanted to mention that I am using Python packages in case somebody has a recommendation on libraries, then please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bimodal data for illustration.** It looks as if sample sizes of your groups are large.
Here are two simulated bimodal samples to use for illustration.

```
set.seed(2020)
x1 = c(rexp(2000, 1/5),   rnorm(1000, 14, 3))
x2 = c(rexp(2000, 1/5.2), rnorm(1000, 16, 3))
summary(x1); sd(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.0031  2.4675  7.1910  8.2074 13.3121 34.6807 
[1] 6.117899
summary(x2); sd(x2)
     Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
 0.00077  2.51898  7.10989  8.83952 14.97832 38.29866 
[1] 6.89922

mx = max(x1,x2)
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
 hist(x1, br=40, xlim=c(0,mx), col="skyblue2")
 hist(x2, br=50, xlim=c(0,mx), col="skyblue2")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

**For large samples, use Welch 2-sample t test.** It is probably OK to to a two-sample
Welch t test to see if we can a find significant differences
in sample means between two such large bimodal samples.
The difference is sample means for my simulated data is highly
significant with a P-value far below 5%.

```
x = c(x1,x2)
g = rep(1:2, each=3000)
t.test(x ~ g)

t.test(x ~ g)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x by g
t = -3.7545, df = 5913.4, p-value = 0.0001753
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.9621210 -0.3020553
 sample estimates:
mean in group 1 mean in group 2 
       8.207435        8.839523
```

The Welch two-sample t test does not assume that the two population
variances are equal.

With large samples the sample means will tend to
be nearly normally distributed. The Central Limit Theorem works for
bimodal distributions. To verify that averages of samples as large as
ours tend to be normal, we can re-sample from `x1`. Ten thousand
averages, re-sampled (with replacement) of size 3000, are nearly normally
distributed as shown in the histogram below. The red normal curve
is a reasonably good fit to the histogram.

```
a = replicate(10^4, mean(sample(x1, 3000, rep=T)))
hist(a, prob=T, br=50, col="skyblue2")
  curve(dnorm(x, mean(a), sd(a)), add=T, lwd=2, col="red")
```

[image]

**Welch 2-sample t test on rank-transformed data.** If there are doubts about the normality of averages of samples from
your bimodal distributions, there are options other than a two-sample
t test to compare population means. One method is to transform the
observations, replacing numerical values in the vector `x` of the
combined samples, with their corresponding ranks from 0 through 6000.
Of course, ranks are not normally distributed, but the span of their
values is limited in a way that often gives near normal averages even
with problematic data.

The Welch t test on rank-transformed data also shows a significant difference in sample mean for my simulated data.

```
t.test(rank(x) ~ g)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  rank(x) by g
t = -3.1079, df = 5945.1, p-value = 0.001893
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
 95 percent confidence interval:
  -226.51287  -51.28447
 sample estimates:
mean in group 1 mean in group 2 
       2931.051        3069.949
```

**Two sample nonparametric 2-sample Wilcoxon test.** Another possibility is to use rank-based nonparametric tests to compare
the two sample means for statistical significance. Here the appropriate test would be a two-sample Wilcoxon rank sum test. It has a P-value very
similar to that of the t test on rank-transformed data.

```
wilcox.test(x ~ g)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  x by g
W = 4291700, p-value = 0.001899
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Depending on the sizes of your samples and the shapes of the bimodal
distributions you want to compare, one of the methods illustrated above
should be appropriate in your situation. (You should choose *one* of the
tests. It would be inappropriate to run all three and pick the one
with the smallest P-value.)